# What should be asserted/tested when inserting an entity in the database/repository

Tags: entity-framework, integration-testing

This is my integration test code:

```
// Arrange
var user = new User() { FirstName = "test", UserId = 4, LastName = "test", RegisteredAt = new DateTime(2013, 02, 02) };
var repository = new GenericRepository<User>(_context);

// Act
repository.Add(user);
_context.SaveChanges();

// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(user.UserId);
```

I have seen people doing a IsNotNull test with the UserId which makes no sense as the UserId should be never a nullable integer.

What and how would YOU test to make sure the entity you created and added into the database is the same?

Would you do:

```
 var dbUser = _context.Users.First(u => u.FirstName == "test")
```

and then

```
Assert.AreEqual(dbUser.FirstName,user.FirstName)
```

and this for all properties you created?

**UPDATE**

I have googled a bit more and the people are really doing different and weird things to test wether an entity was inserted into the database:

```
Assert.That(1, Is.EqualTo(context.Roads.Count()));

Assert.assertNotNull(repo.findUserById(user.getId()));

ICustomer retainedCustomer = repository.
                    Customers.
                    Where(q => q.CustomerName == expectedCustomerName).
                    FirstOrDefault();
                Assert.IsNotNull(retainedCustomer);
```

The first does not even test the inserted entity called road it is checking the count of the road table...
The second and the third assertion seem wrong in my opinion because they use the repository methods with login in it which could fail in a later test to get the inserted customer/user.

What do you think?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of as far as the is not null is concerned is that UserId is an Identity column auto incremented on insert. Thats why it is not in the user instantiation. I would think that the not null test would be sufficient.

Comment: yes the UserId is an identity column auto incremented on insert but then the assert.IsNotNull makes no sense because before this assertion will happen in an error scenario an exception is thrown thus the assertion will never fail because UserId is null. What can not be anyway... its not nullable... I do not understand your answer therefore cameron.

Comment: OR womuld you assert the return value of the context.SaveChanges where 1 means 1 object is inserted and 0 is failed although this is a scenario you can not assert because if the insertion fails there will be an exception in case of a PrimaryKeyViolation etc....

Comment: I made an update to my question.

Comment: I think this question is not really appropriate for StackOverflow. It's hard to give one right answer. It's more a discussion than a question. Maybe the bottom line is: you test what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Gert For me the "affected records" from the SaveChanges() method return value is enough for an ADD test. The rest would be testing the entity framework itself like testing on properties like firstname etc... which is not needed. Yes you are right its more a discussion probably very opiniated statements will be done...